# Como simplificar esse código em Python?

Tags: python

Estou aprendendo Python e deparei-me com um exercício que pedia a criação uma função group() que dividisse os elementos de uma lista em listas menores conforme tamanho pré-determinado, segundo os dois exemplos abaixo:

`group([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3)` resultaria em `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

`group([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4)` resultaria em `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]`

Consegui resolver o problema, porém estou buscando opções mais simples e melhor elaboradas do que a minha, que não me pareceu boa. Alguém poderia, por favor, me ajudar? O código que consegui criar foi o seguinte:

```
    def group(lista, a):
b = []
x = 0
if len(lista) % a == 0:
    for i in range(int(len(lista)/a)):
        b.append([])
    for c in range(len(b)):
        for i in range(a):
            b[c].append(lista[x])
            x += 1
else:
    for i in range(int(len(lista) / a + 1)):
        b.append([])
    for c in range(int(len(b)-1)):
        for i in range(a):
            b[c].append(lista[x])
            x += 1
    for c in range(0, 1):
        for i in range(int(len(lista) % a)):
            b[-1].append(lista[x])
            x += 1
return b
```

Answer (score 4):

Seu código ficará mais simples usando [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def group(lista, a):
  return [list(lista[i:i+a]) for i in range(0, len(lista), a)]

print(group(range(0,100),4))
```

Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MealyMiniatureInstances)

Resultado:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], 
 [20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31], [32, 33, 34, 35], 
 [36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43], [44, 45, 46, 47], [48, 49, 50, 51], 
 [52, 53, 54, 55], [56, 57, 58, 59], [60, 61, 62, 63], [64, 65, 66, 67], 
 [68, 69, 70, 71], [72, 73, 74, 75], [76, 77, 78, 79], [80, 81, 82, 83], 
 [84, 85, 86, 87], [88, 89, 90, 91], [92, 93, 94, 95], [96, 97, 98, 99]]
```

A ideia é fazer `i` percorrer pelos índices de `lista` saltando a cada `a` elementos e então para cada variação de `i` será criada uma fatia de `lista` que irá do índice `i` até o índice `i+a`.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar um algoritmo que seja capaz de dividir uma lista em `N` sublistas. Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
def group(lis, n):
    return [list(lis[i:i + n]) for i in range(0, len(lis), n)]


# Montando a lista:
lista = list(map(int, input('Digite todos os valores: ').split()))

while True:
    try:
        num = int(input(f'Desejas dividir a lista em quantas sublistas? '))
        if num < 1:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite valores maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')

print(f'\033[32mA lista de sublistas gerada foi:\n{group(lista, num)}')
```

**Este algoritmo é mais genérico**. Pois, é capaz de trabalhar com **quaisquer** listas.

Quando executamos este algoritmo recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite todos o valores da lista:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores da lista, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

Após termos digitados todos os valores a lista será montada.

Em seguida, recebemos a segunda mensagem: `Em quantas sublistas desejas dividir a lista:` . Neste momento devemos digitar a quantidade de sublistas que desejamos formar.

A partir desse momento, tanto a `lista` quanto a quantidade de sublistas são passadas como argumentos para a função `group`. Chegando lá, a lista é subdividida pela quantidade anteriormente informada.

Posteriormente a lista contendo as `N` sublistas é exibida.